# AWS Loadbalancer routing request

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using Amazon AWS EC2 to host my web application. My web application is hosted on 2 web servers and having Loadbalancer to manage traffic.
I am using CodeIgniter framework.

My problem is when I try to login to my application, Loadbalancer is routing my request to wrong server and even with correct Login Password I am not able to Login to my application and due to this my session is not started.

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: May I clarify which load balancer service from AWS are you using? You should be looking at enabling the sticky session feature.

Comment: I think its ELB

Comment: Then perhaps check this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html

Comment: Thanx, a lot @junkangli for your quick and helpful support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be enabling the sticky session feature.
If you are using AWS ELB (Classic Load Balancer), then check out how to [configure sticky sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html).

Comment: Solved it!, once again thanx a lot @junkangli  for your quick and helpful support:)

Comment: Glad this answered your question.